# Calabash not considering changes to the core files

Tags: calabash, calabash-android

The screenshots taken by Calabash has numbers appeneded at the end to make it unique. I am looking to remove this and just want the filename without these auto generated number.

As mentioend in the question at
[CALABASH - Renaming screenshot filenames without the iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28353303/calabash-renaming-screenshot-filenames-without-the-iterator) , I have edited code in **lib/calabash-cucumber/failure_helpers.rb** but it's of no help.

Any changes done to the core files are not getting reflected.

I am trying for Android.

Answer (score 0):

```
def screenshot(options={:prefix => nil, :name => nil})
```

screenshot method in failure helpers has path variable appended with screen shot count **`path = "#{prefix}#{name}_#{@@screenshot_count}.png"`**
remove screenshot count and that must work **`path = "#{prefix}#{name}.png"`**

Comment: As mentioned in my questions, changing the files of ruby core does not work.